No broker is available in docker-compose Kafka
I’m setting up Kafka with Docker Compose on Windows, but when I try to run my producer script, I get an error saying the broker is not available. I’m new to Docker, so I might be missing something.
Here is my docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest'
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'

  kafka:
    image: 'confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

and here is my producer.py code:
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json
import time
import random

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092', 
                         value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))


def generate_data():
    data = {
        'id': random.randint(1, 100),
        'value': random.random(),
        'timestamp': time.time()
    }
    return data

while True:
    data = generate_data()
    producer.send('data_topic', data)  
    print(f'Sent: {data}')
    time.sleep(1)


The error I’m seeing is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\Desktop\producer.py", line 7, in <module>
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kafka\producer\kafka.py", line 381, in __init__
    client = KafkaClient(metrics=self._metrics, metric_group_prefix='producer',
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kafka\client_async.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kafka\client_async.py", line 927, in check_version
    raise Errors.NoBrokersAvailable()
kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable

I’ve tried various solutions from other sources, but none have worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Check the container logs to ensure kafka is actually running... Also, you don't need Zookeeper anymore and there's an official Apache kafka image you can use rather than Confluent's

You can try referring docker-compose files here: https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka
